# Is it ever useful to use Python's input over raw_input?

Tags: python, user-input, python-2.x

I currently teach first year university students python, and I was surprised to learn that the seemingly innocuous `input` function, that some of my students had decided to use (and were confused by the odd behaviour), was hiding a call to `eval` behind it.

So my question is, why does the `input` function call `eval`, and what would this ever be useful for that it wouldn't be safer to do with `raw_input`?  I understand that this has been changed in Python 3, but it seems like an unusual design decision in the first place.

[Python 2.x input function documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: It's useful for code-golf

Comment: To answer the “why” – Python's first REPL might have been `while 1: print input()`. I bet at that ancient time, supporting good programming practices was not as high on Python's list of priorities as it is now. Python 3's `while True: print(eval(input()))` might even seem more confusing – all those nested parentheses!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is it ever useful to use Python 2's input over raw_input?

**No.**

---

`input()` evaluates the code the user gives it. It puts the full power of Python  in the hands of the user. With generator expressions/list comprehensions, [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__), and the `if/else` operators, literally anything Python can do can be achieved with a single expression. Malicious users can use `input()` to remove files (`__import__('os').remove('precious_file')`), monkeypatch the rest of the program (`setattr(__import__('__main__'), 'function',  lambda:42)`), ... anything.

A normal user won't need to use all the advanced functionality. If you don't need expressions, use `ast.literal_eval(raw_input())` – the [`literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function is safe.

If you're writing for advanced users, give them a better way to input code. Plugins, user modules, etc. – something with the full Python syntax, not just the functionality.

If you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing, say `eval(raw_input())`. The `eval` screams "I'm dangerous!" to the trained eye. But, odds are you won't ever need this.

---

`input()` was one of the old design mistakes that Python 3 is solving.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, even if you wanted `input`'s functionality, if you did `eval(raw_input())` then you would at least see that it was dangerous.  And there's not really a good reason to use it otherwise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Python Input function returns an object that's the result
of evaluating the expression. 
raw_input function returns a string

```
name = "Arthur"
age = 45

first = raw_input("Please enter your age ")
second = input("Please enter your age again ")

# first will always contain a string

# second could contain any object and you can even
# type in a calculation and use "name" and "age" as
# you enter it at run time ...

print "You said you are",first
print "Then you said you are",second
```

**examples of that running:**

Example: 1

```
Prompt$ python yraw 
Please enter your age 45 
Please enter your age again 45 
You said you are 45 Then you said you are 45
```

Example: 2

```
Prompt$ python yraw
Please enter your age 45 + 7
Please enter your age again 45 + 7
You said you are 45 + 7 Then you said you are 52 
Prompt$
```

Q. why does the input function call eval?

A. Consider the scenario where user inputs an expression '45 + 7' in input, input will give correct result as compared to raw_input in python 2.x

Comment: alternatively they could enter `quit()` which is rather dangerous if you are part way through a critical section of code...

Comment: Or they could input `__import__('os').remove('precious_file')` which is rather dangerous *anywhere*. [`ast.literal_eval(raw_input())`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a much better choice in practically all situations. No wonder [Python 3's input()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) works like 2's raw_input().

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Why do you consider the "correct result" for the input to be 52? I would consider the correct result to be "please enter a number." There is no good reason for a program that asks for a number to compute the result of a Python expression the user may give. Not only is this absurd behaviour, but also a serious security risk as Petr pointed out. The question was "is input useful" and the answer is "no".

Comment: This is not helpful at all, if you want to build a calculator then do it safely through a parser, such as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/6260170

Answer (score 4):

`input` is pretty much only useful as a building block for an interactive python shell. You're certainly right that it's surprising it works the way it does, and is rather too purpose-specific to be a builtin - which I presume is why it got removed from Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` is better, It always returns the input of the user without changes.
Conversely The `input()` function will try to convert things you enter as if they were Python code, and it has security problems so you should avoid it.

In real program don't use `input()`, Parse your input with something that handles the specific input format you're expecting, not by evaluating the input as Python code.