# Checking whether the user input is a number

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare a input that the user receives that checks if the input is actually a number. Here's what I have so far:

```
numstring = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10")
```

and then to compare I have it in a method like this:

```
def check(a):
   if int(a) == int:
       print("It's a number!")
   else:
       print("It's not a number!")
```

It always prints out that it's not a number, even though it is.

Goal of this program:
I'm making a guessing game:

```
import random

numstring = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10")

def check(a):
    if int(a) == int:
        print("It's a number!")
    else:
        print("It's not a number!")

    if abs(int(a)) < 1:
        print("You chose a number less than one!")
    elif abs(int(a)) > 10:
        print("You chose a number more than ten!")
    else:
        randomnum = random.randint(1, 10)
        randomnumstring = str(abs(randomnum))
        if randomnum == abs(int(a)):
            print("You won! You chose " + a + "and the computer chose " + randomnumstring)
        else:
            print("You lost! You chose " + a + " and the computer chose " + randomnumstring)


check(numstring)
```

Thanks for any help! The actual code works, but it just fails at checking it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. He  is using `print()` function. So, I guess 3.

Comment: @RohitJain `print()` works in py2 as well, but prints tuples.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Yeah. Thanks for the info. I know that :)

Answer (score 10):

You can just use [str.`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method:

```
def check(a):
    if a.isdigit(): 
        print("It's a number!")
    else:
        print("It's not a number!")
```

The above approach would fail for negative number input. `'-5'.isdigit()` gives `False`. So, an alternative solution is to use `try-except`:

```
try:
    val = int(a)
    print("It's a number!")
except ValueError:
    print("It's not a number!")
```

Answer (score 5):

`int(a)` and `int` are not equal because `int()` returns an integer and just `int` with no `()` is a type in python2.(or class in python3)

```
>>> a = '10'
>>> int(a)
10
>>> int
<type 'int'>
```

If you're only dealing with integers then use try-except with `int` as others have shown. To deal with any type of number you can use `ast.literal_eval` with try-except:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> from numbers import Number
def check(a):
    try:
        return isinstance(literal_eval(a), Number)
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> check('foo')
False
>>> check('-100')
True
>>> check('1.001')
True
>>> check('1+1j')
True
>>> check('1e100')
True
```

Comment: `isinstance(int("a"), int)` will throw exception. And `'-1'.isdigit()` will return `False`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to cast an input to `int` in `try/except` block:

```
numstring = input("Choose a number between 1 and 10")

try:
    a = int(numstring)
    print("It's a number!")
except ValueError:
    print("It's not a number!")
```

If you are using python 2, consider switching to `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input()` accepts any python expression and this is bad and unsafe, like `eval()`. `raw_input()` just reads the input as a string:

```
numstring = raw_input("Choose a number between 1 and 10")

try:
    a = int(numstring)
    print("It's a number!")
except ValueError:
    print("It's not a number!")
```

Note that `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()` in python 3.

Also see:

- [Python: user input and commandline arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-and-user-input)
- [Is it ever useful to use Python's input over raw_input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709022/is-it-ever-useful-to-use-pythons-input-over-raw-input)
- [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Hope that helps.

Comment: May be OP is using py3.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah, thanks, I've added a link to the relevant thread.

Comment: Your first approach will fail. `isinstance("5", int)` will return `False`. And `isinstance(int("a"), int)` will throw exception.

Comment: @RohitJain sure, it's fragile. But if the OP is using python 2 and the input is 5 - it'll work.

Comment: @RohitJain "5" is not of `int` type - I understand. But, I mean that `input()` will return 5 (int), not "5" - it evaluates the input, reads it as an expression in python 2.

Comment: @RohitJain but, anyway, thank you - I've removed `isinstance` option in order to avoid confusion.