# Python making a string a choice?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Solving a shipping programming problem for school, just started with python 2.7.5, trying to make US or Canada a choice, as it stands I had to make a numerical choice to get this to work, I'm trying to get the choice for the prompt as US or Canada and not assign a number, do I have to declare something as a string? If I use Canada or US it gives me an error message about a global variable. 
rough draft with number choice:

```
def main ():
    user_ship_area = input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada? Type 1 for US, 2 for   Canada') 

    if user_ship_area != 2:
      print 'confirmed, we will ship to the United States '
    else:
      print "confirmed, we will ship to Canada" 

main()
```

I get an Error message when I use Canada or US under if

```
user_ship_area = input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?') 
if user_ship_area != Canada:
    print 'confirmed, we will ship to the United States '
else:
    print "confirmed, we will ship to Canada"
```

Comment: You should write 'Canada' as string literal, not a directive Canada

Comment: You should use `raw_input` rather than `input`. `raw_input` will take a string from the user: `input` will take a Python expression (like an integer 2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709022/is-it-ever-useful-to-use-pythons-input-over-raw-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input`

```
def main ():
    user_ship_area = raw_input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?') 

    if user_ship_area != 'Canada':
        print 'confirmed, we will ship to the United States '
    else:
        print "confirmed, we will ship to Canada" 

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `Canada` will be parsed as variable, but it should be a string. Also, if you're using Python 2.x, then use `raw_input` instead of `input`, because the second one will evaluate your inputted string. So, your code should looks like:

```
user_ship_area = raw_input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?') 
if user_ship_area != 'Canada':
    print 'confirmed, we will ship to the United States '
else:
    print "confirmed, we will ship to Canada"
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a ' mark on

```
user_ship_area = input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?') #<--- here 
  #<--an indent here.  v      v  quotes to indicate string here  
  if user_ship_area != 'Canada':
    print 'You picked Canada!'
```