# Python 3.4 User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, evaluation

I want to write a small script to tell me if the bass level is OK or not from user input.

I am just learning user input, and this is what I have so far:

```
def crisp():
    bass = input("Enter bass level on a scale of 1 to 5>>")
    print ("Bass level is at") + bass
    if bass >=4:
       print ("Bass is crisp")    
    elif bass < 4:
       print ("Bass is not so crisp")
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? From the looks of it you need to convert `bass` to an int. Your first `print` statement also needs to have everything in the brackets.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see a problem here, but just a simple program that does this and only this would be as so:

```
a=1
while a==1:
    try:
        bass = input('Enter Bass Level: ')
        print('Bass level is at ' + str(bass))
        if bass >=4:
            print("Bass is crisp")
        elif bass < 4:
            print('Bass is not so crisp')
        a=0
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Entry')
        a=1
```

Not much difference with a function:

```
def Bass():
    a=1
    while a==0:
        try:
            bass = input('Enter Bass Level: ')
            print('Bass level is at ' + str(bass))
            if int(bass) >=4:
                print("Bass is crisp")
            elif bass < 4:
                print('Bass is not so crisp')
            a=0
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Entry')
        a=1
```

Comment: Your code is with Python 2.x in mind. In Python 3.x, `raw_input` from 2.x is the default behavior of `input` in 3.x. Considering the title mentions 3.4, this answer is technically wrong, but still possibly helpful. For future viewers: **use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2.x code** for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I have not used "try" yet. I will check it out.

Comment: Very useful. as I am learning in 2 and using a 3 interpreter of IDLE.

Comment: @jahrich this answer is inaccurate, first, the indentation is off. Second, **you cannot catch a SyntaxError that way in [tag:python-3.x]**

Comment: @A.J. I corrected SyntaxError to ValueError and fixed the bass var. for 3.4.

Comment: @jahrich please note that in 3.4 print is a function and must be used as print(text, endline char) and cannot have anything outside of the parentheses, or it gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

When you take in `input()` through the built-in function, it takes input as a string.

```
>>> x = input('Input: ')
Input: 1
>>> x
"1"
```

Instead, cast `int()` to your `input()`:

```
>>> x = int(input('Input: '))
Input: 1
>>> x
1
```

Otherwise, in your code, you are checking `if "4" == 4:`, which is never true.

Thus, here is your edited code:

```
def crisp():
    bass = int(input("Enter bass level on a scale of 1 to 5>>"))
    print ("Bass level is at") + bass
    if bass >=4:
       print ("Bass is crisp")    
    elif bass < 4:
       print ("Bass is not so crisp")
```

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x, [don't use `input`, use `raw_input` always](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7710959/786020).

Comment: Yes, @BenMorris,  but in [tag:python-2.x] I would suggest using `raw_input()` :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to an integer:

```
bass = int(input("Enter bass level on a scale of 1 to 5>>"))
```

Comment: Thanks you I did not define bass as an int. :)

Comment: Be sure to upvote or mark as answer.