# Best Python Input method for Integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 2.7, if we take an integer as input, which one is more faster and efficient or there is no difference at all:

input() or int(raw_input())

Comment: Set up a test and find out. Use the `time` module.

Comment: Ignoring timing, the former will not throw an error if you give it not an int. The latter makes more sense if you want to do a try/catch up front.

Comment: Or `timeit` module! Also, speed wouldn't be a big issue, the difference would be in microseconds. First options is basically `eval(raw_input())`, while second is `int(raw_input())`

Comment: Aren't both of these limited by the reaction of the CL user? What's the point?

Comment: I guess it could add up if you're running it on a shared machine with many simultaneous users? Maybe? Probably not. Premature optimization, to be sure, but curiosity isn't bad.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

> **input([prompt])**
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

`int(raw_input())` will be faster, more secure and produce less confusing results.

Consider:

```
>>> b = 5
>>> a = input()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>> a = int(raw_input())
[1, 2, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1, 2, 3]'
```

The `ValueError` raised when reading input is far more desirable than the `TypeError` raised when using the variable.

Comment: Nice answer! I would advocate for putting a small inline comment next to the input statements with what you typed in, like `a = input()  # input: [1, 2, 3]`. Another important note is that `input` in python2 is a [liability](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7710959/4775429) -- I can type any python code into it and it'll be executed by the program.