# Python sequence id to mysql with text

Tags: python, mysql, sequence, pymysql

I m trying to create id numbers with constant strings. But when I execute the program, it is inserting the input number times my input value. I just want to add like:

dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_0
dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_1
dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_2
dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_3
... (to input value.)

Here is m code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='sanane13', db='python')


with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `deneme` (`id_1`) VALUES (%s)"  
        x=0
        y = eval(input("please insert number of students:  "))
        while x<y:

            value = "dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_%s" %y
            x = x+1
            cursor.execute(sql, (value, ))




conn.commit()
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `x` variable to construct the `value`. Replace:

```
value = "dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_%s" %y
```

with:

```
value = "dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_%s" % x
```

---

As a side note, it is usually not a good idea to use `eval()` - [it is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), see:

- [Is it ever useful to use Python's input over raw_input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709022/is-it-ever-useful-to-use-pythons-input-over-raw-input)

Comment: Thank you so much GOD Protects you <3 Me and my friend have been working on this since the morning..