# Print list from user input

Tags: python, list, user-input

its been a while since I worked in python. I have two lists (A and B). If the user types in 'A', I want the output to be list A.

I can't seem to remember how to do it.

```
person = input('List A or B?: ')
person = str(input())

A = ["Mark","Rob","Mary"]

B = [ "Alex","Mitch","Tyler"]



for x in A:
    print x
```

Comment: You mean like this `if person == 'A':  myList=A else: myList=B` .... `for x in myList`?

Comment: @Harvey you could shorten that into a ternary statement or add an elif to check if input is not either

Comment: @AndrewL: I was going to do that, but thought that they might be simplifying the problem for the question and that a ternary statement then wouldn't be appropriate. You're right, though. I should have added the `elif`, too. Just difficult to know what they really want.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I agree fully @Harvey

Comment: this is really simple and seems like homework.

Comment: @AkashLodha - I agree. I think "can't seem to remember how" is being used as a euphemism for "don't want"...

Answer (score 1):

```
person_dict = {
    'A': ["Mark","Rob","Mary"],
    'B': [ "Alex","Mitch","Tyler"]
}
key = raw_input("List A or B:")
print(persons_dict.get(key, None))
```

Comment: It doesn't end up making a difference in this particular case, but the parentheses are not needed for `print` in Python 2. It's only one object, though, so, again, it won't change the output. Similarly, `dict.get()` already returns `None` by default for missing keys. No need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to check what the response is, and you're set:

```
person = input("List A or B? ")

listA = ["Mark","Rob","Mary"]

listB = ["Alex","Mitch","Tyler"]

if person == "A":
    for x in listA:
        print(x)

elif person == "B":
    for x in listB:
        print(x)
```

Note - When giving the interactive response, you must quote it. input() interprets the input, and you will get an error if you reply `B` instead of `"B"`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, this helped! :)

Comment: About `input`: No sane programmer uses this in Python 2.x (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709022/is-it-ever-useful-to-use-pythons-input-over-raw-input))

Comment: @Matthias - Actually, this answer seems to be geared toward Python 3. In Python 2, it wouldn't even work (`person` would be a list rather than a string).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, this seems to be Python 3 while the OP uses Python 2.

Comment: Hey, Im just trying to give the most similar answer to the question. They used input, so I made input work. @Matthias

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer in  python 3

```
def main():
    person = input('List A or B?: ')

    A = ["Mark","Rob","Mary"]

    B = [ "Alex","Mitch","Tyler"]

    myList = []
    if person == 'A':
        myList = A
    elif person == 'B':
        myList = B

    for x in myList:
        print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

I made 'myList' initially empty so it won't display anything if the user doesn't choose one of the options.

Comment: Note that the OP is not using Python 3, as evidenced by their use of `print` as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
a = ["Mark","Rob","Mary"]

b = [ "Alex","Mitch","Tyler"]

person = raw_input('List A or B?: ').lower()

if person == 'a':
    print a

elif person == 'b':
    print b

else:
    print 'Try again'
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to do this, some of which are explained by other users.

I'll show you the quickest (yet most unsafe) way to do this:

```
# Python 3
person = input()
for x in globals()[person]:
    print(x)
```

Example:

```
>>> A = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> person = input()
A
>>> person
'A'
>>> globals()[person]
['foo', 'bar']
>>> for x in globals()[person]:
...     print(x)
foo
bar
```

Comment: The person who downvoted this, care to give an explanation? I think I made it clear enough that it's a quick hack.

Comment: This code makes no sense. You're using `input` in Python 2, which will already evaluate the entered string as a reference to the desired list, and then you're turning that list into a string, and then you're trying to access `globals()` with a key of that stringified list. It is 100% broken.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm sorry, I was in a hurry and just copy-pasted the code from the OP and made the required changes without reviewing them. I have no experience with python2 whatsoever, so I've fixed the code to work for python3 with an appropriate example.