# Python 2.7.10 :Is there any other way to check whether an input is empty other than using len()

Tags: python

I am currently trying to make a maths quiz and I am working on trying to make the program not crash when the user doesn't answer a question(leaving the user input empty).This is what I have so far

```
    useranswer=raw_input("what is 8-5?")
    length=len(useranswer)

    while length<=0:
      useranswer=raw_input("please enter answer")
      length=len(useranswer)

    if int(useranswer)==3:
      print "correct"
    else:
      print"sorry wrong"
```

right now I'm using the method of checking the length of the `useranswer` using `len(useranswer)` to see if there is anything in the input but this only works if i use `raw_input` and not with a normal`input`.

I wanted to know if there is any other easier way of checking if the user input is empty with a different method? I have looked for answers from a few other stackoverflow questions but none of them seemed suitable.

Thankyou!

Comment: `if useranswer:` # tests the truthiness of your string... empty strings are `False`.

Comment: Why are you using `raw_input` and `input`? If you're using Python 2, you shouldn't be using `input()`, it's a potential security hole!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't think the dupe covers it, they're talking about using `input()` in Python 2 (for some unknown reason)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I went by the title when marking... if OP can clarify what they actually want, that'd be great.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Agreed about the lack of clarity

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thankyou for your suggested stackoverflow page to help with my issue. I have looked through it but it doesn't quite seem like what i wanted, but thanks anyway. Also, I have edited my question and have tried to make it more specific so I hope it is ok now.

Comment: Sure, reopened.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use

```
if useranswer:
    # do what you want to do here
```

Comment: STOP right there. Do _not_ use `input` in python2. EVER.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709022/is-it-ever-useful-to-use-pythons-input-over-raw-input

Comment: Basically you are saying using input can take malicious inputs from user. So you are ready to write code to cast the input from raw_input but not ready to Write some validation, that will help you do upgrade in future. instead you want to use raw_input and write all the codes all over again?

Comment: "_instead you want to use raw_input and write all the codes all over again?_" Yes.

Comment: Great all the best, all the best with that.

Comment: `int(raw_input())` is a small number of bytes to pay for security

Comment: int(raw_input) will break for any input other than integer you have to put it into try and handle it, same thing you will do with input + it will solve your casting problem + it will be compatible for higher version of python

Comment: yes, but a bit of wrapper code is a really a small price for security, best practice coding is not code golf

Comment: If you want to move to a higher version of python, use 2to3.

Comment: @binu.py I think this answer worked and is pretty simple. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome @Ruby,you might want to take care of white-space as input depending on your need