# Controlling GPIO in RPI via python 2 input

Tags: python

This is a very simple question that I could not find the answer to via google. I just want to have an input, such as typing Green to turn on a green LED.
Here is my code so far.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)



Green = 'GPIO.output(17, True)'

input ()
```

Typing in green just says the string back. Without the '', it just runs the script and turns the LED on. 
Thanks for your hlep.

Comment: What search terms did you use? It’s odd that you couldn’t find anything relevant on google.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture your input in a variable, like so: `color = input()`

Then you can plumb that input through some logic:

```
if color.lower() == 'green':
    GPIO.output(17, True)
```

Here, I forced the input to be lowercase, so we only account for the input as if it were entered in lowercase, for easy comparison of strings since `"Green" != "green"`

Because there may still be confusion, I amended this answer with the following two examples:

A more complicated example, using a dictionary:

```
def set_color_green():
    # Sets green by calling the output function to the gpio object
    GPIO.output(17, True)

# construct a dictionary with valid values
gpio_func_dict = {'green': set_color_green} # Here, all we need is a function name

color = input()

# guard against capital letters
if color.lower() not in gpio_func_dict.keys():
    raise Exception('You provided an invalid option')

# Call the right function
gpio_func_dict[color.lower()]()
```

And a *dangerous* example using the string...

```
if color.lower() == 'green':
    exec(Green) # getting in the habit of doing this could lead to a long career of security flaws, vulnerabilities, and bugs
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what input.lower is? Im super new to python, I apologize.

Comment: I get this error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/control.py", line 14, in <module>
    if input.lower() == 'Green':
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: So, perhaps it's a wise idea to use a different variable name, like `color =` instead of `input =`, but that error shouldn't happen unless you don't create an `input`. 

Are you actually doing `input = input()` before you call `input.lower()`?

Comment: I created the input, however my output is just sending back the code I typed in.>>> Green
'GPIO.output(26, True)'

Comment: This is python 2 by the way.

Comment: I missed that this was Python2.x, but was surprised to find that masking a builtin like that didn't work in Python2.x. Regardless, I still don't understand your confusion -- perhaps I need to update my answer to add additional information. I think there's an expectation of executing a string -- which is possible if done a specific way, but is really a bad habit

Comment: Also, as a disclaimer: I never deal with GPIO. I assumed your issue was that you were calling `Green` inline or something like that.

Comment: Basically, I want python to execute something based off of the input I type in, I assume I would need to assign a variable, green in this case, to output my command in python. The GPIO command is just GPIO.output(17, True). By learning to do this, I hope to be able to go further in python/pi programming.

Comment: @ZachDavis If you just want to _output_ it to the screen, then fine, print it. But if you want to _execute_ it, the example I have above should be more than sufficient to do just that. I'll even throw in a more complex example, AND a dangerous example!

Comment: @ZachDavis hth, I added two more examples of different ways to do what you're asking. The one in the middle is more "complete", whereas the last one is a modification to the if statement in the original. Definitely be careful, and doing the last one is *for educational purposes only*, I wouldn't get in the habit of doing that, because exec could be extremely dangerous under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use constants for your GPIO pin numbers.  Then when you say change the green-LED to another pin, the code only needs to be changed at a single point.

I moved the GPIO setup code into a single function, and also made the setting of the green LED a function.

The main loop of the program prompts the user to input a command.  If they type 'quit', the loop exits.  If they type 'green' the LED will change state.  The current state is held in the variable `green_led`.

There's an important difference in the `input()` function between Python2 and Python3.  In [Python2 it's best to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7710959/1730895) `raw_input()`, and *not* use `input()`.  One you do have some user input, you need to clean it up to make checking easier.  In the code below, the user_input is first trimmed of spaces with `.strip()`, and then all the letters are made lower-case with `lower()`, meaning something like "AbCDe" becomes "abcde".  This allows us to check whether "  GReen" equals "green" easily, and not have check a bunch of different letter-case combinations.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Pin constants
PIN_GREEN  = 17
PIN_OTHER1 = 21
PIN_OTHER2 = 26

def setupGPIO():
    # Configure GPIO PINs
    GPIO.setwarnings( False )
    GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BCM )
    GPIO.setup( PIN_OTHER1, GPIO.OUT )
    GPIO.setup( PIN_OTHER2, GPIO.OUT )
    GPIO.setup( PIN_GREEN,  GPIO.OUT )

def setGreenPin( status ):
    """ Turn the Green-LED's PIN High or Low """
    if ( status == True ):
        GPIO.output( PIN_GREEN, True )
    else:
        GPIO.output( PIN_GREEN, False )

### Main Loop

# Set the initial state
setupGPIO()
setGreenPin( False )  # start with the LED off

done      = False
green_led = False

# Loop around, reading user commands until they enter 'quit'
while not done:
    user_input = raw_input( "Colour> " )       # get input form the user
    # user_input = input( "Colour> " )         -- python3
    user_input = user_input.strip().lower()    # trim spaces, make all lower-case
    # What did the user say?
    if ( user_input == 'quit' ):               # Is the user quitting?
        done = True            
    elif ( user_input == 'green' ):
        green_led = not green_led              # flip On <-> Off, and vice-versa
        setGreenPin( green_led )
```